# How to set a child element border in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align my child element border inside a td to the same width of the td border.

For example

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td><td>edc <div class="child"></div></td><td>test</td>    
       <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> test </td><td>45g</td><td>block</td><td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td><td>test</td><td>swap</td><td>test</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

CSS - with bootstrap.

```
table {
    border-collapse: inherit;
    border-spacing: 5px;

}

.table>tbody>tr>td {
    position:relative;
    border:solid 3px red;
    padding:0;
}

.child {
    border-left:solid 3px green;
    border-right:solid 3px green;   
    width:100%;
    height:10px;      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfjm7L5y/4/

Basically, I want to show child element of the td border cover the td border so green border is on top of red border. Is it possible?

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: You can give a negative margin to the `div` of `3px` on left and right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting a width of 100%, try letting a block style display handle the width, then set a negative margin for the width of the border:

```
.child {
    border-left:solid 3px green;
    border-right:solid 3px green;
    height:10px;   
    margin: 0 -3px;   
}
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/tfjm7L5y/7/

Answer (score 1):

You could set the position of the div to absolute, get rid of the width, and then just set the left and right properties equal to the width of the border so that it overlays the table cell. Add:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:-3px;
right:-3px;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tfjm7L5y/5/)**